# How to get the HTTP Status Code returned with WinPhone WebClient?

Tags: c#, http, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, webclient

I'm needing to send a piece of text to an HTTP server. I need to know with a decent amount of certainty that is was successfully sent, and not sent to a captive portal or some such. Because of some limitations with the HTTP server though, my best shot for determining that is to ensure that the returned HTTP status code is 200.

How can I get the HTTP status code returned from the server?

This is my current code:

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "text/xml";
        client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        bool? result=null;
        try
        {
            client.UploadStringAsync(server, "POST", data);
            client.UploadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
                {
                    result=e.Error == null;
                };
        }
        catch { }
```

Currently `e.Error` will be set when the server returns a 400-500 error code, but not if the server returns the 300 series of HTTP status codes.

Comment: Question: Does your server correctly return the HTTP codes? e.Result contains the actual response

Comment: @ADNow e.Result currently will be blank *if* it's successful. The only indication of success if a 200 status code. We're trying to detect though if the phone is inside a captive portal though which would redirect all traffic

Comment: I think WebClient is simplified. Can you go dive deeper? If you use HttpWebRequest, you can get the status code as var response = we.Response as HttpWebResponse; var code = response.StatusCode;

Comment: @ADNow Make than an answer an I'll accept it, especially if you give  a quick conversion of my existing code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not have a chance to test this code, however, it might give you an idea or two:

```
 string data;

        var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://yourserver") as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Accept = "text/xml";
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");

        try
        {
            var response = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null);

            // do something with your data, e.g. read it, deserialize it
            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    data = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                // ....
            }

            var somethingInteresting = response as HttpWebResponse;
            Debug.WriteLine("Status is {0}", somethingInteresting.StatusCode);
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            var errorResponse = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
            var errorHttpStatusCode = errorResponse.StatusCode;

            Debug.WriteLine("Here's your error Http status: {0}", ex.Status);
        }
```

Comment: Heh, the funniest thing about all of this is that Windows Phone actually violates a portion of the HTTP spec with this WebClient behavior "If the 302 status code is received in response to a request other than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might change the conditions under which the request was issued."